# how to change page tab application URI slug?

Tags: facebook

At the moment my page tab URI is /page.name/app_1234567890. How can I change that to something normal/readable, like /page.name/tab-name?
There is supposedly the Namespace in the application settings, but it isn't used here for some reason.